# Kiuj podkastoj por komencantoj?

Tags: learning, course, websites

Mi konas kaj mi aŭskultas esperantajn retradiojn kiel Muzaiko-n ktp, sed kompreni ilin estas tro malfacile por mia esperanta nivelo.

Do, ĉu iu konas kie mi povas trovi (tre) facilajn esperantajn podkastojn? Ĉu io ekzistas por komencantoj (senspertaj kiel mi)?

Comment: Kelkaj podkaptiloj permesas agordi la rapidecon. Kutime homoj uzas tion por aŭskulti en duobla rapideco. Sed ankaŭ eblas aŭskulti je 75% de la originala rapideco por pli bone kompreni.

Comment: Tiu estas bonega ideo. Mia podkaptilo ne havas tiu kapablon sed mi povus ŝangi la rapidecon per ĉomputilo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por komencanto, la plej bona loko estas Youtube.

Oni povas trovi multajn videojn, fojfoje kun teksto.

- [Vikifilmetoj](https://www.youtube.com/user/traduki/videos) — simplaj laŭtlegoj de artikoloj (aŭ partoj)
- [BookBox (Esperanto)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPDzF0B97OtGYLPwIiGpRjIXigF6tn1tb) — rakontoj por infanoj
- [Saluton, Ĉinio!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLADdiIFrH-XK-wva8G9wq4vZ8RB3rhQ4Z) — mallongaj videoj pri la kulturo de Ĉinio

Eblas elŝuti la aŭdaĵon kaj uzi ĝin kvazaŭ podkasto.

Aŭskultu, konsultu vian vortaron por nekonataj vortoj, kaj ripetigu la videojn tiom kiom necesas. Neniam rezignu!

Comment: Dankon, sed mi demandas pri podkastoj por auskulti ilin per elreta poŝtelefono. Mi bezonas computilon por youtube

Comment: Serĉu "download youtube audio" kaj vi trovos retejojn, kiuj ebligas transformadon.

Comment: Jes, vi pravas. Mi ne pensis pri ĉi tiu ebleco

Comment: Mi rekomendas http://www.youtube-mp3.org/ . Mi ĉiam uzas ĝin, kaj ĝi ne havas spamecajn reklamaĉojn, kiel havas la plejmulto de aliaj, kiujn mi trovis.

Answer (score 8):

Mi rekomendas [Facila Vento](http://facila.org/) kiu estas retejo kun facilaj tekstoj kiuj estas laŭtlegitaj. Estas du versioj de la sonoj, unu pli malrapida ol la alia, kaj estas ligiloj al difinoj por la plej malfacilaj vortoj. Bedaŭrinde ĝi ŝajne ne plu tiom aktivas, sed almenaŭ la arĥivo povus esti utila. En la subo estas [ligilo](http://facila.org/?feed=rss2) al la fluo de RSS kiu funkcias en podkastilo.

Answer (score 2):

Eble vi povas trovi ion ĉe STUDIO: http://novajhoj.weebly.com/

Ĝi enhavas listojn da filmoj kaj podkastoj kiuj ĝisdatiĝis preskaŭ ĉiutage, mi kredas.

En mia sperto, kiel komencanto kaj nun komencinto (nu, eble), ĉiujn podkastojn kiujn oni aŭskultis ne estas tre facile komprenebla komence, sed post kelkaj semajnoj, se oni aŭskultas ilin ĉiutage, oni trovos, ke plifaciliĝos kompreni ilin.

Aktuale, mi aŭskultas kaj ĝuas la ĉiusemajnan podkaston Kern.Punkto: https://kern.punkto.info/

Pasintece, mi aŭskultis Radio Verda: http://radioverda.com/

Comment: Dankon pro la redakto, Neil. Mi preferas uzi la ĉapelojn, sed la komputilo kiun mi uzis por tajpi la respondon ne havas la kapablon.